# Executing the same command with different arguments in parallel

Tags: bash, xargs

I think that xargs is intended exactly for this, but I tried using it and couldn't figure it out.

I have a command `foo -bar 123 --baz=whatever`. I want a Bash one-liner to run three copies of it in parallel, except they will have a different argument for `123`. Say the first copy will be `123`, the second one is `234` and the third one is `345`. I want the three commands to execute in parallel.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
for arg in 123 234 345; do 
    foo -bar "$arg" --baz=quux &
done
```

Alternatively:

```
echo 123 234 345 | xargs -P3 -n1 -J% foo -bar % --baz=quux
```